# grep a string with some variables in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep, makefile, string-concatenation

I have been struggling like for two hours to figure out the issue regarding this script of mine. When I used it statically without any variable it fetches the grep results, but when I put them with those variables, i keep receiving error and no results. I believe there is something wrong with the special character escape which I can not handle.

I have the file FLAGS_IN with this structure :

```
automotive_susan_s dataset1 -funsafe-math-optimizations -fno-guess-branch-probability -fno-ivopts  -fno-inline-functions  -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -fselective-scheduling -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-tree-pre -ftracer -fno-move-loop-invariants
```

that have the flags for i in AppName and the dataset$j as structured above. Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this part of my sh script?

```
GCC_OPT="-O3"
OPT_FLAGS=$("grep $i\ dataset$j\ $FLAGS_IN|sed\ s/$i\ dataset$j//g")
echo $GCC_OPT
echo $OPT_FLAGS
echo "found the validated flags, they are \n $GCC_OPT $OPT_FLAGS"
make -f Makefile.gcc -j4 CCC_OPTS="$GCC_OPT\ $OPT_FLAG"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a little overzealous with your quoting. Also, it's a little easier to use `cut` here than `sed`.

```
OPT_FLAGS=$(grep "$i dataset$j" FLAGS_IN | cut -d " " -f3-)
```

and

```
make -f Makefile.gcc -j4 CCC_OPTS="$GCC_OPT $OPT_FLAG"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for the grep part (i think you might forget to add $ to FALGS_IN), but still the cut part doesn't prune the matched grep string

Comment: I figured it out, I can use `| cut  -d " " -f3-` to match and exclude. anyways, thanks a lot buddy, if you edit your answer i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat file
foo
automotive_susan_s dataset1 -funsafe-math-optimizations ...
bar

$ i=automotive_susan_s
$ j=1

$ sed -n "s/$i dataset$j//p" file
 -funsafe-math-optimizations ...
```

Comment: yes, it was , i wanted to exclude the matched grep string out of the output which I finally could do it with @chepner answer. but thanks anyway for your answer ;)